# How do you convert string arraylist to double using for loop to calculate?

Tags: java, list, parsing, arraylist, double

I'm given the data.txt file and have to calculate the total amount using `ArrayList`

my data.txt file contains:

32.14,235.1,341.4,134.41,335.3,132.1,34.1

so far I have

```
public void processFile() throws IOException
{
    File file = new File("SalesData.txt");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
    ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line = input.nextLine();

    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");

    while (st.hasMoreTokens())
    {
        arr.add(st.nextToken());
    }

    setArrayListElement(arr); //calls setArrayListElement method

}
```

and here is my `setArrayListElement` method:

```
private void setArrayListElement(ArrayList inArray)
{                
    for (int i = 0 ; i < inArray.size() ; i++)
    {
         // need to convert each string into double and sum them up
    }
}
```

Can I get some help??

Comment: Use `Double.parseDouble()` to convert a `String` to a `double`.

Comment: Please add parameter to you Arraylist in the parameter private void setArrayListElement(ArrayList<String> inArray)

Answer (score 2):

1. Never use doubles for monetary calculations (Previous answer is also wrong)
2. Never refer to a concrete class. The interface in this case is List arr = new ArrayList();

To your specific answer:

```
BigDecimal summed = BigDecimal.ZERO;

for (int i = 0 ; i < arr.size() ; i++) {
 final String value  = arr.get(i);
 try{
  BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(value);
  summed = summed.add(bd);
 } catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
       //TODO: Handle
 }
}
```

...

Comment: Any reason for using explicit indexed access rather than `for(String value : arr)`?

Comment: Correct, not needed an index loop in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Double.valueOf()`:

```
Double.valueOf(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Double value = Double.parseDouble(yourString);
```

Answer (score 0):

I post you the method to calculate the total amount, dont forget to control exceptions.

```
    private Double setArrayListElement(ArrayList inArray) throws NumberFormatException
{   
    Double amount=0;    
    for (int i = 0 ; i < inArray.size() ; i++)
    {
       amount= amount+Double.valueOf(inArray.get(i));
    }
    return amount;
}
```